# Android connection to mysql Database with php server

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database-connection

I am about to make an app that connect to database and update listview every X seconds (connection via WiFi).

My questions:

1. Is it a good solution to keep connected app to wifi and update the list eg. every 10 seconds?
2. What is the easiest way to communicate with database via php scripts?
   I was looking for this and found example with **HttpClient** but in Android Studio it says that this is deprecated. Then I found **HttpURLConnection** but I have got no clue how to use it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you do NOT want to expose your db to the world at large. use a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial:

[How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

1. I think that's not quite good way. That will consume much battery and server's traffic will increase. Try push or increase interval. 10 seconds is too short.
2. Try [this](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request). I use this when I need a connection between server.

Comment: I forgot to add that the device on which the app is going to run will be connected to AC all the time.
What do you mean by "push"?